# update face_detector for electric?

Tags: ros, face-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I submit an attached patch to use the face_detector package in electric environment?
I couldn't find ticket form in https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg

```
Index: test/face_detector_false_rtest.xml
===================================================================
--- test/face_detector_false_rtest.xml  (revision 53029)
+++ test/face_detector_false_rtest.xml  (working copy)
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 
 
-  
 
    
 
Index: test/face_detector_true_rtest.xml
===================================================================
--- test/face_detector_true_rtest.xml   (revision 53029)
+++ test/face_detector_true_rtest.xml   (working copy)
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 
 
-  
 
    
 
Index: manifest.xml
===================================================================
--- manifest.xml    (revision 53029)
+++ manifest.xml    (working copy)
@@ -16,7 +16,6 @@
 
 
 
-
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11253/update-face_detector-for-electric?/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The new ticket button appears once you login.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2